# Weird error when testing angular controller with $httpBackend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I've been trying to fix it for hours. Unfortunately with negative effect so please help me.

In my application I want to test my $http requests. I'm doing it by using $httpBackend.

Here is my controller code:

```
angular.module('app').controller('testController',function($scope,$http){
 $http.get('/test/users').success(function(data){
        console.log('wtf');
    });
})
```

My unit test code:

```
describe('testController tests', function(){
    var $httpBackend, $scope, createController;
    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($injector, ngTableParams, notifier,identity, $sessionStorage, $location){

        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

        $httpBackend.whenGET('/test/users').respond({test: 'test'});

        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');


        createController = function(){
          return $controller('testControler', { '$scope': $scope, '$http': $httpBackend });
        };


    }));

    it('should fetch users ', function() {
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/test/users');
        var controller = createController();
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });

});
```

It's not working. I always have the following error:

```
TypeError: Object function $httpBackend(method, url, data, callback, headers, timeout, withCredentials) {
var xhr = new MockXhr(),
    expectation = expectations[0],
    wasExpected = false;

function prettyPrint(data) {
  return (angula...<omitted>... } has no method 'get'
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/base/public/app/controllers/testController.js:256:11)
at invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/public/libraries/angular/angular.js:3805:17)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9876/base/public/libraries/angular/angular.js:3816:23)
at $get (http://localhost:9876/base/public/libraries/angular/angular.js:6922:28)
at createController (http://localhost:9876/base/test/unit/testControllerSpec.js:70:18)
at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/base/test/unit/testControllerSpec.js:89:26)
at jasmine.Block.execute (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:1145:17)
at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2177:31)
at http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2167:18
```

Any ideas what does it mean and how to fix it?

Comment: try to use `.expectGET` instead of `.whenGET` (in beforeEach)... and in use case, `$httpBackend.expectGET('/test/users');` is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found error in my code. $httpBackend shouldn't be injected into controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you need to add the dependencies to your module creation:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller ...
```

instead of

```
angular.module('app').controller ...
```